# How do I put my randomized number into the GUI?

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.*;

class Boxes extends JFrame{
    ImageIcon image1;
    JLabel label1; 
    JLabel label2;

    Boxes(){
        int random = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
        label2 = new JLabel(random);
        setSize(600,500);
        setVisible(true);
        add(label2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){  
        Boxes frame1 = new Boxes();
    }
}
```

Here is my code for showing the randomize number to the screen 
it is not working

I get an error

> The constructor javax.swing.JLabel(int) is undefined

can someone help me

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're trying to call a JLabel constructor, one that takes a single int parameter, that doesn't exist, and this is not allowed in Java. Per the [JLabel API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html), JLabel has constructors that take a String or an Icon or nothing (plus a few multi-parameter constructors). So change the int into a String:

```
label2 = new JLabel(String.valueOf(random));
```

or

```
label2 = new JLabel(Integer.toString(random));
```

or

```
label2 = new JLabel("" + random);
```